# AWX execution environment pip error ResolutionTooDeep: 2000000

Tags: ansible, pip, ansible-tower, ansible-galaxy

I've been building an execution environment for my awx for a while now and never got any kind of problem, but now I am trying to recreate the same EE I created 1 month ago, and it does not work anymore. It used to take just 15 minutes to build the container, but now it takes 10 hours to fail with the error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 339, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 392, in resolve
    raise ResolutionTooDeep(max_rounds)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionTooDeep: 2000000
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.3; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
[3/3] STEP 1/13: FROM quay.io/ansible/ansible-runner:stable-2.11-devel
Error: error building at STEP "RUN assemble": error while running runtime: exit status 2

pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionTooDeep: 2000000
```

This is my requirements.yml

```
---
collections:
  - name: amazon.aws
    version: 3.3.0
  - name: ansible.netcommon
    version: 2.5.0
  - name: ansible.posix
    version: 1.3.0
  - name: ansible.windows
    version: 1.9.0
  - name: awx.awx
    version: 21.4.0
  - name: check_point.mgmt
    version: 2.3.0
  - name: community.docker
    version: 2.7.1
  - name: community.hashi_vault
    version: 3.2.0
  - name: community.aws
    version: 3.3.0
  - name: community.general
    version: 5.5.0
  - name: community.vmware
    version: 1.18.0
  - name: community.windows
    version: 1.10.0
  - name: community.zabbix
    version: 1.8.0
  - name: google.cloud
    version: 1.0.2
  - name: kubernetes.core
    version: 2.3.2
  - name: netbox.netbox
    version: 3.8.0
  - name: openstack.cloud
    version: 1.6.0
  - name: ovirt.ovirt
    version: 1.6.6
  - name: redhatinsights.insights
    version: 1.0.5
  - name: theforeman.foreman
    version: 3.1.0
  - name: paloaltonetworks.panos
    version: 2.9.0
  - name: cyberark.pas
    version: 1.0.13
  - name: f5networks.f5_bigip
    version: 1.8.1
  - name: fortinet.fortios
    version: 2.1.7
  - name: community.mysql
    version: 3.5.1
  - name: community.postgresql
    version: 2.2.0
```

and this is my requirements.txt

```
urllib3
netaddr
rocketchat_API
cryptography==36.0.2
git+https://github.com/ansible/ansible-builder.git@1.1.0
psycopg2-binary
PyMySQL
```

I always thought that using the versions would let me rebuild the container at any time, but that is not the case.

Any idea what is breaking that?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with ansible-builder and found that cryptography was causing the issue.

Was able to build the container after removing cryptography from requirements.txt.

It may also be worth removing the git declaration of ansible-builder from requirements.txt

Comment: I was also having this exact issue and resolved it by removing community.vmware from requirements.yml. Build time went from 10+ hours and failure to 10 minutes and success.